# Movie involving time-travelling Nazis

Tags: story-identification, movie

Trying to identify a film.  It's possible it was made-for-TV, or even an episode for some sort of *[Outer Limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outer_Limits_%281995_TV_series%29)*-style TV show.  I saw it on TV around 2000 - 2004; it was in color.  It felt like something made in the late '80s or '90s.

The plot involves Nazis time-traveling to the present day.  A major plot element was discovering that the Nazis were trying to steal books about World War II.  Unfortunately, I don't remember much if anything about the time travel device.  It felt like a family comedy -- it wasn't taking itself very seriously and had at least one kid in it.

One scene I remember is a Nazi soldier rolling a ["potato-masher" grenade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_24_grenade) down a hallway into a room of a house, and someone -- possibly the kid -- picking it up and throwing it back.  It's possible it was a smoke grenade; I don't recall an explosion.

Comment: Long shot - [X-files episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_(The_X-Files))?

Comment: @Wikis No, that's not it, sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: Marching Out of Time (1993) - Pic 02]
[image: Marching Out of Time (1993) - Pic 03]

[**Marching Out of Time**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0273788/) (1993)

> Fred Johnson is an average American with a simple life, until he hears
>   peculiar noises next door. His neighbor, Professor Memo, has conducted
>   experiments which have crossed paths with a German time machine from
>   1942. Fred and the professor must find a way to stop the Germans from taking vital information back through time, and change the course of
>   history. Fred calls on police officer Butch, a by-the-book cop, who
>   finds this story absurd... until he too finds himself face to face
>   with the outlandish soldiers. On a roller coaster rescue mission,
>   Butch and Johnson overtake the squadron but it's too late. The records
>   have already been taken back in time, leaving our heroes only one
>   choice.... they must ride the vortex back to World War II --- *Edited
>   from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_Out_of_Time)*

Here's a [clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THjklbzf0PE) :-) Warning: There's a bare butt in there!